# PHP array from function passed onto array on new sheet

Tags: php

I am trying to pass on an array from a function on one sheet into a new array on another php sheet.

Here's what i have:

The function is:

```
//the arr.php file

<?php

function search($var){
$var;

$a=array();
$a[0]=$var+1;
$a[1]=$var+2;
$a[2]=$var+3;
$a[3]=$var+4;
return $a;
}
?>
```

The second sheet is:

```
<?php

include ('arr.php');
$n=4;

for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++)
{

$temp=search(3); 

$thearrayfromarr[$i]=$temp;//doesn't work
print_r($thearrayfromarr[$i]);//doesn't work
}

?>
```

I want the second sheet to have an array variable which i can echo that will output
the $a array data from the search function.

So that, for example, when i type

```
echo thearrayfromarr[0]; // It will have the value of $a[0] echo'd to me
```

Comment: Where is $thearrayfromarr defined?

Comment: @RiverC: It's defined here: `$thearrayfromarr[$i]=$temp;` The first iteration defines it, the next ones add to it.

Comment: Ok, though it is much better to explicitly define it somewhere like $thearrayfromarr = array(); ... Given those two files we don't know if the second is included by something, so where $thearrayfromarr comes from is vague. Plus, scope issues with the for loop.

Comment: @RiverC: I agree, but when you're looping through an array that you know will definitely have values (0-4) it's OK if you're careful. The real issue comes when the array you're building was already defined and you end up adding to it. It's bad style, definitely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function isn't `return`ing anything:

```
function search($var) {
    $a=array();
    $a[0]=$var+1;
    $a[1]=$var+2;
    $a[2]=$var+3;
    $a[3]=$var+4;
    return $a; // Need this
}
```

Comment: If I had more time I'd try to figure out what your code is actually doing an provide an alternative. I assume this is just dummy/sample  code for the purposes of asking a question here, and not your real code? A function called `search` doesn't seem right for whatever this is supposed to do...

Answer (score 0):

Your `search()` function isn't returning `$a`. Here's a cleaned up version that works:

```
<?php
//the arr.php file

function search($var){
    $a = array();

    for($n=1; $n<=4; $n++) {
        $a[] = $var + $n;
    }

    return $a;
}
?>
```

Comment: Cleaned up version would be `return range($var + 1, $var + 4);`

Comment: Quite right @Alexey. However, I think the simple loop illustrates what's actually happening to the OP.

Comment: I fixed the return part, itworks now, but i am trying to make thearrayfromarr in the new sheet have the values of the called function search(3)

Comment: You haven't defined `$thearrayfromarr`. Outside your `for` loop, add `$thearrayfromarr = array();`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply return this array from the function:

```
return $a;
```

If you already return something else, you should declare `$a` as reference argument:

```
function search($var, &$a) {
  $a[0]=$var+1;
  $a[1]=$var+2;
  $a[2]=$var+3;
  $a[3]=$var+4;
  return "something";
}

$a = array();
$temp = search(3, $a);
// $a now has new value
```

Answer (score 0):

The array you define inside the function is not accesible from outside. You need to return the array in order to use it.

**Returning the array**

```
function search($var){
$var;

$a=array();
$a[0]=$var+1;
$a[1]=$var+2;
$a[2]=$var+3;
$a[3]=$var+4;
return $a;
}
```

Then you use it like this:

```
include ('arr.php');
$n=4;

for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++)
{

$temp=search(3); 

$thearrayfromarr[$i] = $temp;
print_r($thearrayfromarr[$i]);
}
```

In this case, if you do: `$thearrayfromarr[0]` should have [1,2,3,4] since you're returning an array, not a value.
This is particularly important since you're hoping for something else according to this line:

```
echo thearrayfromarr[0]; // It will have the value of $a[0] echo'd to me
```

**To answer the question**

How do I make $thearrayfromarr have the value of search(3)?

You don't need the for loop for that, you can just do:

```
include ('arr.php');

$thearrayfromarr = search(3); 
print_r($thearrayfromarr); //should return [4,5,6,7]
```

Comment: I fixed the return $a part, but how do i make $thearrayfromarr have the values of let's say [4,5,6,7] by making search(3)?